# Insert Scope Identity into 2nd table in stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am inserting records into 2 different tables with 1 stored proc. I need to take the scope identity of the 1st table and insert it into the 2nd table under "TableId". What I'm doing below is NOT working for @Identity. Any ideas?

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[campVideo]

    @DateCreated datetime,
    @CustomerId int,
    @VideoName varchar(100),
    @Identity int OUT,
    @UserID int,
    @DateTime datetime

AS  
BEGIN

Insert Into Table1 (DateCreated, CustomerId, VideoName)
    Values (@DateCreated, @CustomerId, @VideoName)
    SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Insert Into Table2 (UserID, DateTime, Table1Id)
    Values (@UserID, @DateTime, @Identity)
End
```

aspx code is here:

```
string strConn = "mydatasource";       

    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("campVideo", Conn);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateCreated", DateTime.Now.ToString()));        
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", strId));
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VideoName", flv_filename));
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", strId));
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
    SqlParameter ClientIDSource = Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Identity", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id");
    ClientIDSource.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: What you mean by 'not working '? Any errors?

Comment: I get no error because im working in .ashx page and don't know how to get error report for ashx. but i narrowed it down to the "table1Id" field because it I manually add a variable such as @Table1Id = "1", then it works

Comment: So what do you mean by 'not working', then?  What's your expected behavior and what's the actual behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use IDENT_CURRENT instead of  SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Try to take a look  [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

*"SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the last identity value created in the current session"*

Comment: the article you link said to use scope_identity

Comment: I am not sure, but for me it's look like the SCOPE_IDENTITY() will take the last identity related to the session, not to the specific table.
For this reason i guessed it will be better to do something like

 SET @Identity = SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('campVideo') 

and the use it as a normal varialble.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table Table1 in your query does not have an Identity column.
In order to get the latest inserted ID using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), you need to have an identity column in the table you are inserting. See the schema of Table1 in SQL Server Management Studio verify there is Identity Column.

Here is the sample. Hope this helps:

Alternatively, you can view this in SQL Fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9906/3

```
    create table #Table1 (Table1_ID int identity(1,1),DateCreated Datetime, CustomerId int, VideoName varchar(100))
    create table #Table2 (UserID int, [DateTime] DateTime, Table1Id int)

    DECLARE @DateCreated datetime
    DECLARE @CustomerId int
    DECLARE @VideoName varchar(100)
    DECLARE @Identity int
    DECLARE @UserID int
    DECLARE @DateTime datetime


    SET @DateCreated = '2014-04-10'
    SET @CustomerId = 1
    SET @VideoName = 'videoname'
    SET @Identity = 0
    SET @UserID = 2
    SET @DateTime = '2014-04-10'

    Insert Into Table1 (DateCreated, CustomerId, VideoName) Values (@DateCreated, @CustomerId, @VideoName)


    SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT @Identity as Latest_Identity_Value

    Insert Into Table2 (UserID, DateTime, Table1Id) Values (@UserID, @DateTime, @Identity) 

       select * from Table2
```